# wkhtmltopdf javascript: element clientWidth returns zero

Tags: javascript, css, wkhtmltopdf

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
function init() {
   var x = document.getElementById("MAIN");
   console.log("clientWidth:" + x.clientWidth.toFixed());
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
</div>
<div id="MAIN">
<p>Check</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome, IE11, and QtWeb, the console shows non-zero result, which is what I expect, e.g.:

```
clientWidth:1219
```

However, if I try to convert it with wkhtmltopdf, I always get 0 as an answer:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf.exe --debug-javascript wktest.html wktest.pdf
Loading pages (1/6)
Warning: file:///C:/work/pm_doc/test/wktest.html:6 clientWidth:0
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

I also tried using `window.computedStyle(element).width` - same result. How do I get element displayed width when running javascript under wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? I've got the same problem.

Comment: No, I haven't. Been using a workaround since.